# Editing fluidLayouts.css in dreamweaver cc for image width and height

Tags: css, responsive-design

Am trying to set a image width and height in the fluidLayouts.css file for the fluid layout, for which am building a RWD website via dreamweaver cc.

Now image width is been taken (in percentages), how do i set image height which will fit for mobile, tab and desktop? I mean should i set the height in pixel or percentage, So to fit any image in mobile, tab and desktop?

Awaiting for an response, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below media queries of standard devices -

```
 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) { /* Styles */ }


 /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (min-width : 321px) { /* Styles */ }


 /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) { /* Styles */ }


 /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) { /* Styles */ }


 /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) { /* Styles */ }


 /* iPads (portrait) ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) { /* Styles */ }


 /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) { /* Styles */ }


 /* Large screens ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) { /* Styles */ }


 /* iPhone 4 ----------- */ 
 @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) { /* Styles */ }
```

In which you can write your css code as per the device.

Comment: But what about the 'height' for any image? how do i show that?

Comment: @Sharath-designer not need to set height, your can set `height:auto;`. just set the width, height will auto consider as per the width.

Comment: Suthar: I forgot mention that am trying set a height for background-image. I guess height:auto; wouldn't work for this one....any other way?

I even tried: background-size: 100% 100%; the height squeezes though.

Comment: try this - `body { background: url(background-image.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed; }`